# how to take input as password in javascript promt box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to take input password in java script prompt box but it only take input as string which is visible  now  how i can take input password in same text field. 
is there any way to change this text field from input type text to password without div

this is what i have already tried

```
prompt("enter password");
```

here is example

[image]

can any one suggest me how i can do this using j query or java script

Comment: You can't do this with a prompt - you have 0 control over it.  You should look at using a dialog with something like jQueryUI or similar.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, referenced question don't ask for jquery

Comment: @Engineer you find any solution for it ?? using javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't.

The popup is browser controlled and can't be changed.

you can use javascript dialog box for it

**HTML CODE**

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <input type="password" size="25" />
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
 $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv7y3/)**

Answer (score 1):

`prompt` is native browser functionality, and therefore not very flexible. Unfortunately, you cannot mask the input from a prompt.

Alternatively, you can use the input element with the password type:

```
<input type="password" size="25" />
```

And show this in a custom modal window. An input element with the `type="password"` attribute set, will automatically mask the entered characters. On how to embed this in a modal, there are many possibilities. If you are using jQuery, you might want to consider using jQuery UI for this:
http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: tell me other solution how i can solve it

Comment: Better yet. How about searching first?

Comment: @Engineer He gave you a solution, YOU have to do something with it now, custom modal + regular password type input is the best and probably one of few other ways the way you want it.