# portable password dialog in javascript

Tags: javascript, dialog

I have a web page, and am trying to add password protection to it, so, if say a user presses a 'send' button, but was not authenticated, a dialog would appear asking for a password.   I originally thought of using prompt to ask for the password, and came across [how to take input as password in javascript promt box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23754317/how-to-take-input-as-password-in-javascript-promt-box).  It appears that prompt does not hide the text (which I would want).

I could create a custom dialog box, but at that point, I'm concerned there might be some corner cases where varous browsers might block the dialog box from appearing (mainly I'm concerned with phones/browsers with ad-blockers, etc).   Am I going to run into trouble, or is there another way to prompt for passwords?

Comment: Dont use prompt. Use htmls password input

Comment: Browsers won't block a dialog box that's implemented as simple HTML/CSS, and that includes mobile browsers.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy   That was my concern.  Implementing as custom dialog box (with htmls password input).

Answer (score 0):

you can use a .htaccess file to protect your page

```
<Files page_to_protect.php>
AuthUserFile /www/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
AuthName "the message that you want display" 
AuthType Basic 
Require valid-user
</Files>
```

and this is the .htpasswd file :

```
your_name:your_passwd
```

finally, just add this below to your button, and it will works perfectly

```
<a href="page_to_protect.php"></a>
```

if you are not on linux, you can create the .htaccess and .htpasswd files with Notepad++